# Question about moving\sharing Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-10

I am taking a class for Python and am using a Jupyter notebook.  When I installed it it gave a  narrow list of places I could save the notebook to.

I have a study share folder in my dropbox I would like to save it to; that way I can access it from my work vm, my desktop, or my laptop. All three of which are on Windows 10.

Is this supported?  How would I go about doing this, as it seemed like it only wanted to save it under `C:\program file\....`?

Jupyter is the current version as of two weeks ago.

Comment: If they're all Windows 10 why not just save it to One-Drive?

Comment: Changing the directory that jupyter starts in might help. On Windows: https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#change-jupyter-notebook-startup-folder-windows

Comment: Thanks for the beginner notebook, its just changing the target.  I should have it from here, thanks.  I will follow up either way.

Comment: So far it mostly worked, but im getting a bug\glitch I am not understanding.  I redirected to the correct folder and saved my notebook there on Comp1.  I saved a print line at the end that is print('testing the share') then saved again and closed, reopened and that was there.  Comp2 shows it just synced and I see the file, i open it and I am only seeing the version before the test share line.... so im still working on it.    Bur abc, thanks for the hand up, i think i am on the right path.

Comment: @abc, i got it.  edit the exe change the target, but ALSO change the very last section of start in, that is in the quotes.  I am bouncing saves between my comps now, thanks a lot this will make training from different locations with ALL my notes MUCH easier, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Google Colab for a couple of reasons:

- Can be accessed from any computer that is signed in to Google
- Jupiter notebooks can be shared just like every other file in Google Drive
- It is free
- No install required

You will want to install the Google Drive add-on. This can be done by going to Google Drive and clicking on the new in the top left. This will show a drop-down. Select more and then click connect more apps. In the pop-up window search for Google Colab and click install.

This will make it so from Google Drive you can press the new in the top left then select more in the drop-down select Google Colab. This will make a new Jupiter notebook in Google Drive. You can also just upload your Jupyter notebook to Google Drive and double-click to open it.

To download your Jupyter Notebook from Google Drive you can side click on the file inside of Google Drive and click download. It downloads just like a normal file in Google Drive.

Google Colab main website: https://colab.research.google.com/

Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/

Sorry if this is over-explained. I figure it was better to explain too much than not explain enough.

Comment: Thanks, i prefer too much info to not enough.

I already have a paid for DB account, any reason I cant  use that?

Comment: Jupyter has put the file into C:\users\(username)\*.  My issue is when in Jupyter it wont let me look outside of that folder, the folder icon wont let me search elsewhere nor will anything else i can see.